# how to get input in jupyter on vs code , i try to run input() function to get input from pop up textfield, but it goes in infinte loop,

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y20zv.png) how to get input in jupyter on vs code, I try to run input() function to get input from pop-up textfield, but it goes in an infinite loop. pop up textfield does not open at all.

how to get user input from notebook cell while running input() function.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3lg6.png)

Comment: Can you paste a snippet of your code?

Comment: Can you post a complete screenshot since in my project, the text field is shown at the top of VS Code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the code cell, Jupyter would pop up a blank Textfield. Input in it instead of Terminal:

[image]